# I read the FAQ about deletion but something's not right…

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-questions

I was casually looking at my bounty stats when I noticed one of the questions I answered had been deleted. The question was posted in March 2016. For the sake of brevity, below are the facts.

1. The question was not automatically deleted by the system
2. The OP did not delete their post. It was deleted **five months later** by *three* members of the EL&U community.
3. **The question had a positive score of +4** (6 upvotes vs 2 downvotes)
4. **The question had received ten answers**, six of which had positive scores.
5. The most popular answer had **a positive score of +8**.
6. The OP had awarded a bounty to an answer (2 upvotes)
7. Two answers had a negative score; -2 and -1 respectively

I looked at the relevant [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) and found an explanation

> 4. **Users with reputation ≥ 10k** (more precisely, the moderator-tools privilege; 2k on beta sites) can vote to delete questions that have been closed/put on hold or marked as duplicate for 48 hours. It takes three votes to delete; more if the question is popular, but ten votes at most.

Further along, under

### How can I undelete one of my posts?

> If your post was deleted by trusted users or by the Community user, it will require three undelete votes to be undeleted - politely asking for this on the per-site meta may attract the necessary votes if you make a good case for why the question should be restored.

### But…

### **what if the OP didn't know their question had been silently deleted five months later?**

- Why isn't there more transparency? An OP should be notified when their question, with three or more positive score answers, is about to be deleted by members of the community or by the system. They should be given a chance to "fix" their question. When you cast a vote to delete an old post, it is silent. The question is not bumped on the active page.
- What about the 10k and 20k users who might want to preserve the post and its answers if they knew it was at jeopardy?
- I don't think the OP was aware of the situation but if they had been at least informed, they might have cast an undelete vote or visited meta and asked the community for clarification, assistance, ideas etc.
- It would be efficient and save a lot of grumbles if 10k and 20k users were notified when a closed but *upvoted* question with an *accepted* and *upvoted* answer was due to be deleted. They would have several options available: they could choose to ignore the notification, verify that the post offers little to no value and promptly delete it or rush in and save the post.
- As to its closure, I retain that the question was on-topic, I posted the following comment beneath the OP

> It would be easier if you edited and added a bit of "research", do you want to reopen it? Note that only four users have put this question on hold, one of them is a moderator

The OP didn't reply, probably by then they were exasperated. But if they had known that a closed question risks being deleted one day, the post could have been fixed easily. Literally, on EL&U we're speaking about adding a dictionary definition.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/notice-of-deletion

Comment: *What about the 10k and 20k users who might want to preserve that question and its answers* that is where we have the review tools for, no?

Comment: I think SO want to be excluded from this but let me run some numbers first.

Comment: @rene well until very recently, I didn't think an upvoted question with upvoted answers could be deleted from the archives. I've always associated deletion with blatantly off-topic posts, LQ, and abysmal answers (if any). It's one thing closing a borderline question quite another to  delete it.

Comment: For one thing, at least on SO, I know duplicates with upvoted answers are deleted on a daily basis by 20K-ers.  That is a thing for a long time already

Comment: [Here is the first dataset](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1057101#graph) deleted questions with the sum of the answer score > 0. Based on that stat alone if your FR was implemented on SO, around 200 notifications would go out to roughly 15,000 users each month ...

Comment: @rene and how many of those questions had one or more upvoted answers? Or an answer that had been awarded a bounty? You can't compare SO with EL&U, size wise it's like comparing China with Austria.

Comment: Around [100 each month](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1057104). I can't find bounty info for deleted posts as that is removed from the votes table. I know SO is the odd one out here. I mention SO to prevent a feature being rolled on us that helps small sites but does a disfavor for larger sites.

Comment: @rene What is this feature?

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog *It would be efficient and save a lot of grumbles if 10k and 20k users were notified when a closed but upvoted question with an accepted and upvoted answer was due to be deleted.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we allow others to delete questions with well-received answers if the asker himself can't delete that question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328739/should-we-allow-others-to-delete-questions-with-well-received-answers-if-the-ask)

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog you want to lump my question with another that has -21 votes and only 4 +. Thanks!

Comment: That question was downvoted mainly because it was phrased as a rant. The answer there is applicable here.

Comment: Again, it's mostly because of the *answer* to that question. Here on Meta, it's acceptable to close questions as duplicates even if they're merely related, provided the answer addresses this one. See [this section of our FAQ on how Meta Stack Exchange works](/a/47635/377214) and the last section of [our FAQ on duplicate closures](/a/10844/377214).

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog I'm quite aware of how most things work. I have closed questions for being duplicates myself, although here I wasn't successful recently. But when I select an "original" question, I make sure the question is clear, on-topic, not closed, relatively popular and it has good, if not great, answers. So be it. I don't really care that much about meta.